# How to add variable to another variable's name

Tags: python, python-2.7

so I have a loop, and I want to call a variable for example name and add x from a loop to the end of the variable's name, so it looks like name0.

for example:

```
for x, var enumurate(something):
    name + x = something
```

it gives me out error.

Comment: Any time you think you need to do this, you should be using an array or dictionary, not dynamically-constructed variables.

Comment: Use a container, such as a list or a dictionary, rather than trying to roll your own.

Comment: You could achieve something like that but please don't do it. Just don't do it. Variable variable names are the first step on your road to hell.

Comment: I understand that it's bad, but it's neccesery for me, I save myself from repeating each line, any examples ?

Comment: No, I'm sure it's not necessary. Please learn about data structures like `list` and `dict`. They will do what you want, but in a much cleaner way. Maybe you could enhance your question by describing why you think you need variable variable names?

Comment: Could you give me some examples Matthias ?

Comment: It is neccesery, sorry I can't give you the code, it will be very hard to understand and I want to keep stuff basic.

Comment: Read about [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is possible, but should not be done.

```
>>> foo = ['fee', 'fie', 'foe', 'fum']
>>> for i, val in enumerate(foo):
...     exec 'foo%s = %s' % (i, repr(val))
...
>>> foo3
'fum'
>>> foo[3]
'fum'
```

What you are asking for is a typical beginner error.  Refering to the fourth item in `foo` as `foo3` has no advantages over writing `foo[3]`.  You can iterate over `foo` without having to know how many items it has.  You can mutate `foo` if you like.  You can refer to the last item in `foo` as `foo[-1]` without having to know it has four items.  Also, the name `foo3` is nonsensical.  It tells the reader of the code nothing about why the items in `foo` are so important that they would need a name.

Comment: I will try to replicate, I do for the last time need an erray off, variable1, variable2 for further in my code.

Comment: Also, I'm not a rookie, I'm working with networking, this simple thing keeping me from progressing.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, again, what I need is variable + variable = further code.

Comment: You mean *you think* you need a variable number of variables, and *you think* you are not a rookie.